# Meteor synchronous and asynchronous call to read a file

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am new to Meteor. I am using following code to read a file stored at server.

> Client side

```
Meteor.call('parseFile', (err, res) => {
  if (err) {
    alert(err);
  } else {
    Session.set("result0",res[0]);
    Session.set("result1",res[1]);
    Session.set("result2",res[2]);
  }
});
let longitude = Session.get("result0");
let latitude = Session.get("result1");
var buildingData = Session.get("result2");
```

> Server Side

```
Meteor.methods({
  'parseFile'() {
    var csv =  Assets.getText('buildingData.csv');
    var rows = Papa.parse(csv).data;
    return rows;
  }
})
```

The problem is while I make a call it takes time to send the result back and hence wherever i am using latitude and longitude its giving undefined and page breaks. So, is there any solution to avoid this problem. One of the solution can be to make a synchronous call and wait for result to be returned.

Comment: "One of the solution can be to make a synchronous call", not on the client, no. You can't make synchronous calls on the client, you'll need to make your page robust to this. I would suggest implementing a "loading page" that waits until the session variables are set on only then render whichever page it is that breaks.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the server method run synchronously using the [futures package](https://atmospherejs.com/jaredmartin/future), which should force the client to wait for the method to complete.

It might look something like this:

```
Meteor.methods({
  'parseFile'() {
    var future = new Future();
    var csv =  Assets.getText('buildingData.csv');
    var rows = Papa.parse(csv).data;
    future.return(rows);
    future.wait();
  }
});
```

This would require you installing the futures package linked above and setting up your includes properly in file containing your `Meteor.methods()` definitions. You might also look into good error handling inside your method.

UPDATE:
The link to the Future package is an NPM package, which you can read about [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/future). The link above is to the atmosphere package, which looks like an old wrapper package.

Comment: Is "Futures" package npm or atmosphere?

Comment: It's an NPM package. Added an update with the link to the NPM version.